# Creative Accounting

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-crosswords

*Sometimes, you just need to make your numbers look a little better. Exaggeration is a mathematical concept!*

[image: crossword grid]

**Across**

**1.** Hesitant to drop ninth scolding (6)
**4.** Bird is eating element 108 (4)
**8.** Score of Yale's leading climber (3)
**9.** British cook briefly hosting fifteen for pastry (7)
**10.** Chaotic being pees about—score losses in competitive recital? (8, 3)
**11.** Three-hit attack: Shoot and drink? (6, 5)
**13.** Alien eaten by groom—one below 28 (7)
**14.** Robot from 2013's disc lacks nothing (3)
**15.** Tens of experts (4)
**16.** Table for four ordered tar in brew (6)

**Down**

**1.** Originally, evangelist's life story contained a dozen sins (5)
**2.** ABBA's 22 cover: myself and Swift leading church elders first with verse (5, 6)
**3.** Atheist peacekeepers exist, with fifteen in bar (10)
**5.** Non-governmental politician to support man and woman hosting 102 (11)
**6.** Roadblock on 22nd that is grand and extravagant, primarily (5)
**7.** Terrible data: eighteen gaps, missing southeastern creature (5, 5)
**11.** Reddish waters hold constant, just over 18 (5)
**12.** Send twenty-five up to support brief aid for twist (5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crossword solves to

> [image]

and a little arithmetic confirms that we are dealing with a

> HYPERBOLIC FUNCTION.

A few words of explanation in case the above doesn't suffice to make it clear:

> in every clue there is a number, and all of those numbers are too large. The amount by which each has been increased, converted to a letter by A1Z26, spells out (in clue order) HYPERBOLIC for the across clues and FUNCTION for the down clues. HYPERBOLIC means "pertaining to exaggeration" as well as its mathematical meaning, of course.